# Automate Opening Files in Photoshop Template

Tags: photoshop, batch, action

I'm trying to automate the process of creating a 3-photo collage.

So far I've automated placing 3 photos and 'clipping' them to the right size (see below) via a Photoshop Action.

My question is if I can **automatically open the next 3 photos in a folder into this template and save it**. I already tried duplicating the template, opening all duplicates and Automate/Batch-ing the action on all open files. This works but results in the same 3 photos in all collages.
[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to automate processes in Photoshop often I would suggest looking into writing custom scripts for photoshop [http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html]. I also suggest posting this question in Stack Overflow for programming questions. In addition, if you only need this one task done you could probably go to a freelancing site and get the job hired out.

Comment: Thanks Cody! I will ask it in the programming section :)

Comment: @mat Photoshop Actions can't handle conditional operations like _choosing next 3 photos in a folder_. It is only possible via scripting.